# Rails Gems Symbolic Links Setup on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, symlink

I have Rails 3, and have been using a Gemfile to install several gems like annotate and rspec-rails

Problem is in all the tutorials, it says to type things like "annotate" in the command line but it doesn't work "command not found" this make me believe that Symbolic Links are not in place to allow me to run/use the gems in terminal.

How do I enable this for all current and future Gems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> sudo gem install annotate
```

Do you have it installed by `sudo`?

Rails 3 and gems works no different than Rails 2.  The commands should be available so long as you use `sudo gem install`.

My wild guess. Try this :

```
bundle exec annotate
```

Comment: I wasn't sure so I reinstalled annotate with the command you gave above which worked fine.. But running "annotate" still does not work. Is there some path or Symbolic Link setup required?

Comment: Try my guess above because its installed in bundle, to execute the gem through bundle you must prepend the command with `bundle exec`. Also make sure you ran `bundle install`